# Blocking calls on android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-resources

I am creating an `Android` app for blocking contact numbers on android . I am stuck in `AndroidManifest.xml`. `Android studio` is giving this error while I have an `icon.png` file in my `res/drawable`!
image is [here](http://postimg.org/image/fm9h0ku2v/).

I have no idea how to turn simple app into system app!image of error is [here].[2](http://postimg.org/image/ohob82dcz/)

Comment: website i am following for code is http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the .png from your manifest file.
You don't need to add the file extension in manifest file
or layout file. Just the name, without the file extension, will do.
So, your entry should look like this:

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

Comment: i did that even then it's not working . it's the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the ".png" from you manifest, you do not define that here. Also: You should provide proper drawables for different display densities. You could e.g. use this online generator to get them [Android Assets Studio : Launcher icons](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)
2. When you want to use the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permissions your users will most likely need an open bootloader and root to use your app. You can find some instructions [here](http://su.chainfire.eu/). You can't move apps to /system without mounting system rewritable, which you need root for. Alternative: Users have to use a custom recovery to push the app to /system, which requires an open bootloader at least.